# Selecting Cells in raster layer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip, arcscan

I am working on a watershed analysis project. The goal of the project is to create a model that will simulate changes the effect that different land uses will have on the watershed as a whole.

Using python, I need to create a user friendly model that will allow a non-tech savvy person to accomplish the following:

"Paint"/select a group of cells in a raster land use layer and then change to their desired land use. For example, the user may wish to see what effect changing a certain area from developed industrial to forest would have on the watershed.

I have tried several options and have not had much luck with any of them.

Clipping a raster based on a polygon that the user would draw around the area they want to change. The problem with this approach is that the raster layer that is clipped is not easily merged back in with the original raster layer.

ArcScan - Raster painting toolbar: this tool seems as though it should work, however, it is limited in the way it will let you select cells. Rather than letting you select individual cells to then change, it will only let you select cells that are connected. This is easy enough to do within the attribute table of a raster layer.

Does ArcMap support the ability to select individual cells within a raster layer to then change those selected cells?

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools out there, a simple search on Google threw up these:

- [Aris Grid Editor](http://www.aris.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=210%3aaris-grid-editor-for-arcmap&catid=64%3aarcgis-tools&Itemid=161)
- [RasterEdit](http://www.coulthard.org.uk/downloads/downloads.htm)